# duda de recursividad

Tags: c++, recursión, visual-studio-2010

comparto este código en el cual se trata de ingresar datos de productos de una tienda usando recursividad , bueno mi duda es a la hora que uso la recursividad para comparar los resultados sobre los montos de cada producto para que me diga cual es el monto que mas se repite me sale error,cambiando variables me sale 0 y en otras error directamente y no se que hacer :/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct inventario{
    char nombreitem[100];
    double unid, precio,unouno;
    int cod;
};
double totalfinal(inventario inven[],int n,double acumulador){
    if(n==0)
        return acumulador;
    else{
        inven[n-1].unouno=inven[n-1].unid*inven[n-1].precio+(inven[n-1].unid*inven[n-1].precio*0.18);
        acumulador +=inven[n-1].unouno;
        return totalfinal(inven, n-1 ,acumulador);
    }   
}
//mostra el monto total que mas se repite con recursivdad
double mostrar(inventario inven[],int n,int cont){
    if(inven[n].unouno==inven[n-1].unouno)
        return cont;
    else{
        cont +=1;
        return mostrar(inven,n,cont);
    }
    cout<<"el numero que se repite es "<<mostrar(inven,n,cont);
}
int egresar(inventario inven[],int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else{
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del producto "<<endl;
    cin>>inven[n-1].nombreitem;
    cout<<"codigo del producto"<<endl;
    cin>>inven[n-1].cod;
    cout<<"ingrese las unidades "<<endl;
    cin>>inven[n-1].unid;
    cout<<"ingrese el precio unitario "<<endl;
    cin>>inven[n-1].precio;

    cout<<"-----------------------"<<endl;
    return egresar(inven, n-1);
    }
}
/*
void ingresar(inventario inven[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del producto "<<endl;
    cin>>inven[i].nombreitem;
    cout<<"codigo del producto"<<endl;
    cin>>inven[i].cod;
    cout<<"ingrese las unidades "<<endl;
    cin>>inven[i].unid;
    cout<<"ingrese el precio unitario "<<endl;
    cin>>inven[i].precio;
    cout<<"-----------------------"<<endl;
    }
}*/

/*
void mostrar(inventario inven[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"nombre "<<inven[i].nombreitem<<endl;
    cout<<"codigo del producto "<<inven[i].nombreitem<<endl;
    cout<<"num de unidades "<<inven[i].unid<<endl;
    cout<<"precio "<<inven[i].precio<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------"<<endl;
    }
}*/
int mostrarles(inventario inven[],int n){
    double res;
    res=inven[n-1].unid*inven[n-1].precio+(inven[n-1].unid*inven[n-1].precio*0.18);
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"nombre "<<inven[n-1].nombreitem<<endl;
    cout<<"codigo del producto "<<inven[n-1].nombreitem<<endl;
    cout<<"num de unidades "<<inven[n-1].unid<<endl;
    cout<<"precio "<<inven[n-1].precio<<endl;
    cout<<"uni x precio"<<res<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------"<<endl;
    return mostrarles (inven,n-1);
    }
}
void main(){
    inventario inven[5];
    int n,cont;
    double acumulador=0,t1=0;
    cout<<"Cuantos productos se va a ingresar? ";
    cin>>n;

    cout<<egresar(inven,n);
    cout<<mostrarles(inven,n);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<mostrar(inven,n,cont);
    cout<<" el precio total es: "<<totalfinal(inven,n,acumulador);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la parte recursiva que te causa problemas? Por lo que veo todas tus funciones son recursivas.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus en la de double mostrar(inventario inven[],int n,int cont) , en esa parte debe comparar los precios de cada producto(unidx precio unitario) con el sgte y decir cual es el precio que mas se repite

Comment: me olvide mencionar que la salida la enlace con la principal tal como se ve en void main         cout<<mostrar(inven,n,cont);

Comment: `el monto que mas se repite me sale error,cambiando variables me sale 0 y en otras error` ¿Que error te sale?